# Extract key value from JSON using python NameError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am creating a python script to extract values, Name from the JSON Key Details from the JSON result. Python error mentioned KeyError 'details[name]'. The JSON example is found below. The JSON is incomplete. JSON has other data which I am not going to put it here as it is confidential.

```
details: {'id': 5555, 'name': 'Timothy', 'Gender': 'Male'}
```

My Python script is shown below

```
print(json_data['details[name]'])
```

Error Message

```
print(json_data['details[name]'])
KeyError: 'details[name]'
```

I want to print the result

```
Timothy
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The syntax you want is `json_data['details']['name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `json_data` is the name you've chosen for the entirety of the JSON object, you need provide a proper index for `json_data` in your print statement. Your current index is a `string` because you've captured your brackets inside of the apostrophes. The way you're indexing the JSON object is also incorrect.

JSON objects are essentially multidimensional dictionaries. The way you print the value of a value of a key is like this: `print(dict["key"]["value"])`.

Assuming the `details` key is also a string, the correct way to print the value of `name` from the key `"details"` is: `print(json_data["details"]["name"]`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

do it one key at a time rather than trying to fit both the keys into one set of quotes as you originally had.

```
print(json_data['details']['name'])
```